# Extending Findinstance

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The answer to this

```
FindInstance[⌊12.25/λ + .5⌋ +  ⌊12.645/λ + .5⌋ == 4, λ]
```

is

```
FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are 
 insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist.
```

Has some one any idea to solve this in Mathematica ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FindInstance[ Rationalize[Floor[12.25/\[Lambda] + .5] + Floor[12.645/\[Lambda] + .5]]
 == 4, \[Lambda], Reals,2]
```

> $$\left\{\left\{\lambda \to \frac{337}{65}\right\},\left\{\lambda \to \frac{496}{65}\right\}\right\} $$

Comment: `FindInstance[ Floor[12.25/λ + .5] + Floor[12.645/λ + .5] ==  4, λ, Rationals, 3]` works too.

Answer (score 2):

```
FindInstance[⌊12.25/λ + .5⌋ +  ⌊12.645/λ + .5⌋ == 4, λ, Reals]
```

> {{λ  -> 6.6123333}}

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

```
Reduce[⌊12.25/λ + .5⌋ + ⌊12.645/λ + .5⌋ == 4 // 
  Rationalize, λ, Reals]

(*  2529/500 < λ <= 49/6  *)
```